# Safari cache issue on second page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm really confused about this issue. I have a website that works perfectly in all browsers except safari. In safari, the first time you visit each page is fine, but when you come back to a page the second time the javascripts are not loaded at the right order, which leads to errors. I assume the issue is some kind of cache going on. The website is [www.core18.org](http://www.core18.org).

this happens both on safari on windows and on mac.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: He asked about Safari and not Chrome. And indeed there is a problem

Comment: Hmmm a sneaky edit methinks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the problem as I can't see the site on Safari atm.
If you believe it's a caching issue, maybe add to the body tag onunload=''?